# define environment spanning two columns

Tags: floats, columns

In writing a two-column paper, I want to insert two figures. Fig. 1 has two subfigures (a) and (b); Fig. 2 has a single figure. So in total, there are three figures, each occupying about 1/3 of the entire page width.

I know commands like "figure*" can insert multiple subfigures in a SINGLE figure environment, but not for this case. Any thoughts?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: sounds like `figure*` to me, why do you think not? what did you try?

Comment: Yes, figure* is right. In fact, in figure*, we can further inserting mnipages. My find the solution by myself, see below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strip` environment, from `cuted`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{cuted}

\usepackage{graphicx, subcaption, caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text. Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.

Some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text. Some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text.

\begin{strip}%\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = off}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Piero_di_Cosimo_3}
    \captionof{subfigure}{}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Piero_di_Cosimo_3}
    \captionof{subfigure}{}
  \end{minipage}
  \captionof{figure} {Two portraits of Simonetta Vespucci}
  \vskip4ex
  \includegraphics[width =0.8\textwidth]{Piero_di_Cosimo_1}
  \captionof{figure} {The death of Procris – ca 1500}
\end{strip}

\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]